# Getting the dimensions of a dynamically-created WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview, size, height, width

I'm embedding a flash media player in a webView in android, and I need to get the dimensions of the webView to set the media player to match. If I hard-code the pixel dimensions of the player in the call, it works, but I want it to adjust based on the dimensions of the webView, which uses android:width=fill_parent and android:height=wrap_content, and change depending on screen orientation.

From what I've read, I've tried waiting for onCreate() to finish and calling getHeight() and getWidth() in the onStart() and onResume() methods, but they both still return 0. Here's the method I call in onStart()

```
private void playVideo(String path){
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    int videoHeight = webView.getHeight();
    int videoWidth = webView.getWidth();
    webView.loadUrl("*my url here*?video="+path+
    ".mp4&width="+videoWidth+"&height="+videoHeight);
}
```

For some reason I always get 0 as the height and width, whether I call the method in onCreate(), onStart() or onResume(). Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `WebView` is a heavy component and its possible that it has not been fully rendered on the screen before you tried to get its width and height.

A simple work around would involve putting the `WebView` into another container preferably a `FrameLayout` and getting the dimensions of the `FrameLayout`.

The dimensions of the `WebView` would always equal those of the `Framelayout` as long as it is the only child and both its width and height are set to `match_parent`

Comment: I've tried that. I used:
`int videoHeight = ((FrameLayout) webView.getParent()).getHeight();
int videoWidth = ((FrameLayout) webView.getParent()).getWidth();`
and I still got 0 for both dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You need the **width** and **height** of the WebView **CONTENTS**, **after** you loaded your **component**.
YES you do, but there is no **getContentWidth** method (only a view port value),
AND the getContentHeight() is **inaccurate** !

Answer: sub-class WebView:

1. /*   Jon Goodwin
   */ package com.example.html2pdf;//your package

   import android.content.Context; import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.webkit.WebView;

   class CustomWebView extends WebView {
   public int rawContentWidth   = 0;                         //unneeded
   public int rawContentHeight  = 0;                         //unneeded
   Context    mContext          = null;                      //unneeded

   ```
   public CustomWebView(Context context)                     //unused constructor
   {
       super(context);
       mContext = this.getContext();
   }   

   public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) //inflate constructor
   {
       super(context,attrs);
       mContext = context;
   }

   public int getContentWidth()
   {
       int ret = super.computeHorizontalScrollRange();//working after load of page
       rawContentWidth = ret;
       return ret;
   }

   public int getContentHeight()
   {
       int ret = super.computeVerticalScrollRange(); //working after load of page
       rawContentHeight = ret;
       return ret;
   } //========= }//class //=========
   ```